# database design issue and mails deleted upon account removal

Tags: mysql, sql, email

My site is comprised of two types of users,regular users and business users and super admins. All of them are listed in a users table(name,email,password) with the addition of busines_users table that holds business-only related info of the business users(type of business, address, etc).

And there is a 3rd table that holds of the mails of the site. Mails sent from the regular users to the business_users OR the super_admins(support etc...).

As such this mails table has 2 cols(from,to) where they reference the userID column is the users table.
And here is the problem, suppose the business_user deletes his account.I intend deleting also the mails that he has sent(whether they are towards the regular users or the super admins)
The problem is that the way the mails table is structured it is inevitable that deleting the mails described above, I will delete also the mails sent to HIM by the regular user of super_admin.

There are 2 scenarios examined:

1. Delete no mails at all-at which case, the discussion ends here.
2. Redesign the db so that mails sent to him are not deleted(the reg_users will still have the mails in their screen), but on the other hand mails send by him are deleted.

What do you propose? If going with 2nd option how I should design the db.
Here are the 3 tables:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `alternative_appointm`.`users` (
`user_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
`lastname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
`email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`password` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`hash` VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`usertype` ENUM('1','2','3','4') NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_ID`) ,
 INDEX `fk_users_usertype1_idx` (`usertype` ASC) ,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_users_usertype1`
 FOREIGN KEY (`usertype` )
 REFERENCES `alternative_appointm`.`usertype` (`type_id` )
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `alternative_appointm`.`business_users` (
`crID` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
`address` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`url` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`phone` VARCHAR(20) NULL ,
`city` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
`municipality` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
`bus_user_type` ENUM('1','2','3','4','5') CHARACTER SET 'latin1' NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`crID`) ,
 INDEX `fk_business_users_buz_usertype1_idx` (`bus_user_type` ASC) ,
 INDEX `crID` (`crID` ASC) ,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_business_users_buz_usertype1`
 FOREIGN KEY (`bus_user_type` )
 REFERENCES `alternative_appointm`.`buz_usertype` (`Type_id` )
 ON DELETE CASCADE
 ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_business_users_users1`
 FOREIGN KEY (`crID` )
 REFERENCES `alternative_appointm`.`users` (`user_ID` )
 ON DELETE CASCADE
 ON UPDATE CASCADE)
 ENGINE = InnoDB
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8


CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `alternative_appointm`.`mails` (
`message-iD` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`from` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`to` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`datetime` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`subject` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`message` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`message-iD`) ,
 UNIQUE INDEX `message-iD_UNIQUE` (`message-iD` ASC) ,
 INDEX `fk_mails_users1_idx` (`from` ASC) ,
 INDEX `fk_mails_users2_idx` (`to` ASC) ,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_mails_users1`
 FOREIGN KEY (`from` )
 REFERENCES `alternative_appointm`.`users` (`user_ID` )
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_mails_users2`
 FOREIGN KEY (`to` )
 REFERENCES `alternative_appointm`.`users` (`user_ID` )
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
 ENGINE = InnoDB
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On table `alternative_appointm.mails` You have to integrity constraints. Currently:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_mails_users1`
FOREIGN KEY (`from` )
 REFERENCES `alternative_appointm`.`users` (`user_ID` )
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
```

And

```
 CONSTRAINT `fk_mails_users2`
 FOREIGN KEY (`to` )
 REFERENCES `alternative_appointm`.`users` (`user_ID` )
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

First step would be to add `'ON UPDATE CASCADE'`, you should do that on most constraints, it means if you ever update a user id it will directly be updated on the `from` or `to` columns.

Next thing is that when a user is deleted on the `users` tables you want to delete all mails  he send and not the one he receiveid. So you only want to delete mails where you can find the user id in the `from` column.

So update the first constraint, only this one, not the one about the `'to'` column:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_mails_users1`
FOREIGN KEY (`from` )
 REFERENCES `alternative_appointm`.`users` (`user_ID` )
 ON DELETE CASCADE
 ON UPDATE CASCADE,
```

The second constraint will prevent deleting the user if some data reference the user id that you want to delete. To allow the deletion you should empty the field (`NO ACTION` is the same as `RESTRICT`)
By using this constraint:

```
 CONSTRAINT `fk_mails_users2`
 FOREIGN KEY (`to` )
 REFERENCES `alternative_appointm`.`users` (`user_ID` )
 ON DELETE SET NULL
 ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

You will have a working deletion, mail sent to this user are still on the table, but, you do not have the id of this user in the 'to' column, (and this id does not exists anymore). You could use a transaction to alter the rows impacted and set a special id in the 'to' column, something like a default 'deleted user' user account id. On postgreSQl you would have the 'ON DELETE SET DEFAULT', but this does not exists in MySQL AFAIK.

Comment: your logic seems correct,but there is an issue which might make the redesign unavoidable. Since the "to" column will have no user_ID to reference anymore...since he would have been deleted, the "from" user which might be any other user in the db will NOT know where his/her mail was sent.                                                       This is my main problem user.

Comment: Well, if you want to keep the name and id of any user sending messages you cannot delete them, for sure, or store another column in the association table, with the user name, so that after deletion you still have the old username there.

Comment: One correction...the purpose is to keep the name of the user receiving the mail(which is going to be deleted) so that the user who sent the mail knows form whom that mail was intended for. Otherwise your suggestion is correct. And one more thing. What rules other web apps with mailers in them do in similar situations. I do not think I am describing a unique problem here

Comment: Some never delete users, some do not care about deletion problems, some ask for a known user to transfer old content, some manage a default 'old deleted shared user', some duplicate information that have to be kept after deletion (like the name here), especially if theses information can be updated (like pseudos) and should not be taken at read time but on the time the message was sent. Most messaging systems in databases store the full rendered content, containing sender pseudo and such in the message.